# affine transformation on the sphere

Tags: curve-fitting

I have 2 sets of points that are restricted to live on the 3D unit sphere, call them {pi} and {qi} (I'll assume correspondence is known). The goal is to register one set to the other, through rotations and translations. Typically I would have used a transformation of the form:

P = RQ + T

where R is a rotation matrix and T a translation vector.

But in this case there is an extra constraint that all points must live on the sphere, how can I include this condition.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the sets are 'rigid', so you can slide and rotate the whole set on the sphere, but can not change distances between points within a set, all possible transformations are *rotations*.

Whenever you rotate the set relative to some axis, points move in planes perpendicular to the axis. So all displacements are vectors normal to the axis vector. So each two displacement vectors should make a vector product parallel to the axis vector.

Now, if you already know the correspondence between P and Q points, calculate displacement vectors *di* from each *qi* to a corresponding *pi* and calculate some vector products:

> *di* × *dj* =  (*pi* - *qi*) × (*pj* - *qj*)

If they have directions close enough to each other, you can assume you have the rotation axis.

Now for each pair or *pi,qi* find a point *ti* on an axis such that the PQT triangle is normal to the axis. The angle at the T vertex defines the rotation to slide *qi* to *pi*. If all respective angles are equal, you're done. Otherwise you'll have to seek some approximate solution...

Comment: Thanks for the prompts answer, isn't there a way to frame the answer as a 2D translation and rotation? intrinsically our data still lives in a 2D manifold. The nice thing about having a linear form for the solution is that we have an analytical solution (remove the mean and use the covariance matrix) with the proposed aproach wouldn't we loose this interpretation?

Comment: Also, is there any benefit to using quaternions to find the needed rotations?, what would the actual algorithm look like when optimizing for the rotation matrices.

Comment: Is there a modified [Kabsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm), for points on the sphere?